# Django Download third party video instead of opening in new/same tab

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am currently trying to make a user download a video on clicking a link . But everytime on clicking the URL(href) it opens it a new tab. The video URL is a third-party URL(Instagram CDN).
Here is my code snippet in my template.html for the page .

```
<a target="_parent" href="{{ story.url }}&amp;dl=1" rel="noopener noreferrer" style="text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0px;color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;" download>DOWNLOAD</a>
```

I intentionally added '&dl=1' to the URL part hoping it might make some impact. This makes the images link downloadable but not the video links. Removing/Adding the attribute 'download' seems to have no impact.

What should I do to force download it and not open in new tab

Comment: try googling `Content-Disposition`

Comment: I assume content disposition for server side requests. My request is not going to the server, but instead directly for download to third party.

Comment: Is there a url for people to download it on the 3rd party site??

Comment: @KshitijSharma so the url is 3rd party url?

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed Correct. URL : https://scontent-del1-1.cdninstagram.com/v/t72.14836-16/76969629_504397123742918_2842272728590243923_n.mp4